# Prove that the binomial algorithm implies the arbitrage free price at t=0 of a T-claim

Tags: arbitrage, risk-neutral-measure, binomial, risk-neutral

In Tomas Bjork's [Arbitrage Theory in Continuous Time](http://f3.tiera.ru/2/F_Finance/FD_Derivatives/Bjoerk%20T.%20Arbitrage%20theory%20in%20continuous%20time%20%28OUP,%201998%29%28ISBN%200198775180%29%28T%29%28S%29%28324s%29_FD_.pdf) (or [here](http://ideabuds.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/Tomas-Bjoerk-Arbitrage-Theory-in-Continuous-Time.pdf)), $\exists$ these propositions

[image: Prop 2.24]
[image: Prop 2.25]

How does the first formula follow from from the algorithm? I get that $\Pi(0;X) = V_0(0)$, but I don't really get what $E^{Q}[X]$ means...is that equal to $q_uu+q_dd$? Anyway using the algorithm I got $V_0(k) = \frac{1}{(1+R)^T} \sum_{l=0}^{T} V_T(k+l)q_u^{T-l}q_d^{l}$...is $\sum_{l=0}^{T} V_T(l)q_u^{T-l}q_d^{l}$ supposed to be $=q_uu+q_dd$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is the way that Björk proposes, however I believe "my" way below is more elegant. The trick in Björk's case is to realize that in each "iteration" we get an expeted value:

$$V_0(0) = \frac{1}{1+R}\left(q_u V_{1}(1) + q_d V_1(0) \right) \\ = \frac{1}{(1+R)^{2}} \left( q_u^2 V_2(2) + 2q_uq_d V_2(1) + q_d V_2(0) \right) \\ = \frac{1}{(1+R)^{2}}E^Q[V_2].$$

Continuing in the same fashion you will arrive at

$$V_0(0) = \frac{1}{(1+R)^{T}}E^Q[V_T],$$

however to make this formal you should make some kind of induction argument.

**My Method**:

My methods does not use **Proposition 2.24** but instead the fact that we already know the single period Binomial Model and the Law of total expectation. We already know that **Proposition 2.25** holds true if $T=1$ since this reduces to the single-period Binomial model. So assume that $T \geq 2$ and assume that **Proposition 2.25** holds true for $T-1$ periods. We when know from the induction assumption that.

$$ \Pi(1; X) = \frac{1}{(1+R)^{T-1}}E^Q[\Phi(S_T)|Z_1] $$

But

$$ \Pi(0; X) = \frac{1}{(1+R)}  E^Q[\Pi(1; X)],$$

and hence

$$ \Pi(0; X) = \frac{1}{(1+R)}  E^Q[\Pi(1; X)] = \frac{1}{(1+R)^{T}} E^Q[E^Q[\Phi(S_T)|Z_1]] \\ = \frac{1}{(1+R)^{T}} E^Q[\Phi(S_T)].$$

This concludes the proof of **Proposition 2.25**

**What does $E^Q[X]$ mean:**

If $Z_1,...,Z_T$ are independent random variables

$$E[f(Z_1,...,Z_T)] = \sum_{z_1,...,z_T=\text{u or d}} f(z_1,...,z_T)P(Z_1=z_1)\cdots P(Z_T=z_T) \\ = \sum_{z_1,...,z_T=\text{u or d}} f(z_1,...,z_T)p_{z_1} \cdots p_{z_T}. $$

This sum means that we sum over all possible outcomes/paths. Since we often use a martingale/risk neutral probability measure it is convenient to introduce the notation to denote the expectation under the probability measure $Q$.

$$E^Q[f(Z_1,...,Z_T)] = \sum_{z_1,...,z_T=\text{u or d}} f(z_1,...,z_T)Q(Z_1=z_1)\cdots Q(Z_T=z_T) \\ = \sum_{z_1,...,z_T=\text{u or d}} f(z_1,...,z_T)q_{z_1} \cdots q_{z_T}.$$

In your case $X=\Phi(S_T)$ which is a function of $Z_1,...Z_T$. Note also that $S_T = su^Yd^{T-Y}$ where $Y$ is the number of up-moves. The sum above over all outcomes can also be written as in Björk, using binomial coefficients:

$$E^Q[f(Z_1,...,Z_T)] = \sum_{z_1,...,z_T=\text{u or d}} f(z_1,...,z_T)q_{z_1} \cdots q_{z_T} \\ = \sum_{j=0}^T {T \choose j}q_u^j q_d^{T-j}\Phi(su^kd^{T-k})$$.

I hope it all checks out, I'm used to a different notation when working with the Binomial Model!

Comment: Is $V_T$ the value of the replicating portfolio at maturity? I guess it's equal to the payoff at T since it replicates the claim? Thanks. I think I'll stick with the induction argument since total expectation was not discussed in this class.

Comment: Yes, exactly! A naive version of total expectation is usually introduced in a first class in probability theory. See Wikipedia for more info, if you're interested:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. It was discussed in one of our stat classes but not in this class so I guess we must prove it some other way. Thanks!

Comment: Is $E[V_i]$ the expected value of the replicating portfolio at time i under martingale measure?

Comment: Oh side note: Our stat prof was surprised to hear that total expectation was not discuss in our prob class hahaha

Comment: Usually you write $E^Q[V_i]$ to denote the expectation under the martingale measure, if it is not clear from the context.